# module 'caffe' has no attribute 'set_mode_gpu'

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe

I have installed caffe from source. I have used the Cmake for installation. I have updated the respective paths as well.
My caffe root directory is: /home/ashj/caffe
I have updated the PYTHON path as: 
`export PYTHONPATH=<caffe-home>/python:$PYTHONPATH`
which is by using 
`**export PYTHONPATH=/home/ashj/caffe/python:$PYTHONPATH`**

I could load import the module caffe. However I am not able to access any methods or any layers inside the caffe like set_mode_gpu(), set_mode_cpu() or layers or params. I am getting errors like:

When I used

> import caffe
>
> caffe.set_mode_gpu()

I am getting following error:

> `Traceback (most recent call last):`
>
> `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`
>
> `AttributeError: module 'caffe' has no attribute 'set_mode_gpu'`

PS: I have also tried using caffe.__caffe.set_mode_gpu() as mentioned in [this link.](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/issues/373#issuecomment-186678800) but it is not working for me.
My system specs: Ubuntu 18.04

TIA

Comment: did you also `make pycaffe` and `make distribute`?

Comment: I did 'make pycaffe' but I did not do 'make distribute'. 'make pycaffe' did not throw any error.

Answer (score 1):

Though may be late, but I encountered this same problem and found a way work around:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/caffe/python')
import caffe
caffe.set_mode_gpu()
```

namely, add the `caffe/pathon` path to you `sys.path` before `import caffe`.
Wrote a [post here](https://www.oukohou.wang/2019/01/16/reocrds_of_installation_errors_and_operations/#32-solution) for detailed analysis, hope helpful.

---

This problem may be the results of package `caffe`'s path.

For me, if I do the following from the Ubuntu Terminal, everything goes fine:
[image: from_terminal]

but if I do from the Pycharm IDE, errors occur:

[image: from_pycharm]

note that I tested the package `caffe`'s path in both ways, and got different results:
- in the Ubuntu terminal, namely the way which goes fine, I got

```
'/home/CVAR-B/softwares/caffe/caffe/python/caffe/__init__.pyc'
```

which is the expected result;
- in the Pycharm IDE way, namely the way error occurs, I got

```
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/caffe/__init__.pyc'
```

which is not the expected result.

In view of this discovery, I did this one more thing to handle the error:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/caffe/python')
import caffe
caffe.set_mode_gpu()
```

namely, add the `caffe/pathon` path to you `sys.path` before `import caffe`.

and the result shows this can be a workaround:
[image: pycharm_IDE_success]
<sub>(source: [ax2x.com](https://s1.ax2x.com/2019/02/25/5jquKK.png))</sub>

See the `caffe.__file__`'s result, now returns the expected path.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps and then set your python PATH:
You might've already done steps 1 and 3.

```
make all 
make pycaffe
make distribute
mkdir ~/python 
mv distribute/python/caffe ~/python
```

Set your PYTHONPATH after this — this should be some dir like `caffe/python/caffe`

Comment: I did steps 1 and 2 again. However, step 3 returns, below error:
`make: *** No rule to make target 'distribute'.  Stop.`

Comment: Hm. I was assuming that you set your python paths in `Makefile.config` before you ran `make pycaffe`. Can you double check?

Comment: Thanks for your response LeKhan. But I am using the cmake steps as given in this link below and hence did not set python paths before running 'make pycaffe'.
http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html#compilation

Comment: Hm, not familiar with the cmake steps. However, I would still make sure to install the dependencies in the requirements.txt. I would also double check that your python paths look ok in the Makefile.

Comment: Finally, I could install caffe by using virtual environment in conda.